# Lopsided Number of Extensions

Tags: wordpress, drupal, extension

This is just a general question:
As a newbie, I'm wondering yhy are there so many more Drupal extensions than WordPress extensions? Just curious, since WP has a larger market share than any other CMS. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just historical. Civi started with drupal and mambo/joomla. But most extensions are designed to work with all CMSs and where possible it's encouraged to make them "CMS agnostic" that way.